# Unable to install VirtualBox on Ubuntu 12.10: Kernel headers cannot be found

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to install Virtualbox on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit, (Kernel 3.5.0-23). I've already installed dkms, build-essential, linux-source, linux-kernel-headers, ... . I still get this error:

> Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.5.0-23-generic cannot be found.
>   Please install the linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic package,
>   or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located

The kernel headers and source are in their appropriate place:

```
ls /usr/src
linux-headers-3.5.0-23          linux-source-3.5.0
linux-headers-3.5.0-24          linux-source-3.5.0.tar.bz2
linux-headers-3.5.0-24-generic
```

I know there are tons of similar questions on different forums, I've tried all of them. None of them works. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? 3.5.0-24 was released today and it looks like you have downloaded it but virtualbox thinks you are still running kernel 3.5.0-23. You can also try running 'uname -a' from the command line to find your kernel version.

Answer (score 10):

Install the kernel headers for your system by running this command in your terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Answer (score 2):

Install the kernel headers for the running kernel

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Or simply use the `linux-headers-generic` to install latest release kernel headers.

> **NOTE**: If you have Hardware Enablement Stack (backported) kernels installed on a LTS release, use the `linux-headers-current` package to install the latest kernel images + headers.

For example, on Ubuntu 12.04, the release kernel is 3.2.0, the linux-current-generic installs 3.8.0-27.