# Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.13.0-69-generic cannot be found - Can't Update!

Tags: boot, package-management, kernel, dpkg

When trying to upgrade, I get this error:

> Not enough free disk space
>
> The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 81.8 M free space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 81.8 M of disk space on '/boot'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'.

Then when I follow the instructions to free up space, I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic* linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic*
  linux-image-3.13.0-64-generic* linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic*
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic* linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic*
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-64-generic* linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic*
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-69-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 9 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 929 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 180855 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-69-generic (3.13.0-69.112) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-69-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-69-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-69-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-69-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-69-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.13.0-69-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.13.0-69-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-69-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-69-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-69-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.13.0-69-generic: No such file or directory
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.13.0-69-generic
Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.13.0-69-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_1pM5O4/lib/modules/3.13.0-69-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_1pM5O4/lib/modules/3.13.0-69-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-69-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-69-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-69-generic
```

I've followed many recommendation on how to fix this issue but it always returns the same error about the "no such directory"

Any help would greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try and free some space first by purging out old unwanted packages using:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

..and then try again with the header install using:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: It always gives the same error - tells me that it is going to remove linux-image-extra-3.13.0-69-generic but ends up with the same output as I originally posted.

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

from: [Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.5.0-25-generic cannot be found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264520/error-your-kernel-headers-for-kernel-3-5-0-25-generic-cannot-be-found?rq=1)

Comment: That returns nearly the exact same message....thanks though

Comment: @SoarX Did this fix your problem?

Comment: No, still exact same issue - some how I need to force the removal of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-69-generic or do it manually but I don't know how to do it....