# nvidia driver not detected. Screen is on low resolution

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa. Today Software Update updated my computer and probably my nvidia driver as well, which broke it.
Now instead of being 1920x1080 my resolution is 1024x768 and I cant fix it.

I googled thoroughly and tried many solutions, but none worked.

I tried disabling `nouveau`.

I tried disabling secure boot (it wasn't turned on in the first place)

I tried reinstalling my driver via `apt` (`nvidia-driver-390`), multiple times, with `--reinstall`, and with `purge`

I tried editing the grub file and added `nomodeset` to line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

I tried xrandr `--newmode` and `--addmode`, which made a new resolution option to appear in my settings, but when I press it, nothing happens, and it just reverts back to 1024x768.

I didnt try yet to install an older driver or install manually with a .run file from the nvidia website. Please help

Here are the outputs of various commands:

```
$uname -r
5.8.0-45-generic


$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GF106 [GeForce GTS 450] driver: N/A 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: fbdev,nouveau unloaded: modesetting,vesa 
           resolution: 1024x768~76Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0 128 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.2.6


$lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF106 [GeForce GTS 450] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: CardExpert Technology GF106 [GeForce GTS 450]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)


$xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* 


$modprobe nvidia
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='nvidia_current_updates'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_current_updates': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)


$dkms status
nvidia, 390.141, 5.8.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)


$ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000DC4sv000010B0sd00000401bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF106 [GeForce GTS 450]
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin


$sudo lshw -numeric -C display
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF106 [GeForce GTS 450] [10DE:DC4]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fc000000-fcffffff memory:d0000000-d7ffffff memory:d8000000-d9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff


$sudo nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.


$nvidia-detector
nvidia-driver-390


$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-390:amd64                   390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-390                       390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64                390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:i386                 390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:amd64                 390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:i386                  390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:amd64                 390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:i386                  390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:amd64                   390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386                    390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:amd64                     390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:i386                      390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:amd64                   390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386                    390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.8.0-41-generic  5.8.0-41.46~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-41
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.8.0-43-generic  5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-43
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.8.0-44-generic  5.8.0-44.50~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-44
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.8.0-45-generic  5.8.0-45.51~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-45
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-390                   390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-390                            390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-390                          390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-390                   390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-390                   390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.16~0.20.04.1                      all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-390                           390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                    0.18build1                            all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390              390.141-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver

#xorg output after nomodeset and disabled nouveau
    $ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
    [    23.504] (--) Log file renamed from "/var/log/Xorg.pid-841.log" to "/var/log/Xorg.0.log"
    [    23.506] 
    X.Org X Server 1.20.9
    X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
    [    23.506] Build Operating System: Linux 4.15.0-130-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
    [    23.506] Current Operating System: Linux pc 5.8.0-45-generic #51~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 23 13:46:31 UTC 2021 x86_64
    [    23.506] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-45-generic root=UUID=005201d6-46a7-465a-8a50-ed834b952d3e ro quiet splash nomodeset vt.handoff=7
    [    23.506] Build Date: 17 January 2021  09:13:31AM
    [    23.506] xorg-server 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
    [    23.506] Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
    [    23.506]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
    [    23.506] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
    [    23.506] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Mar 16 12:28:59 2021
    [    23.509] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
    [    23.509] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
    [    23.512] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
    [    23.512] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
    [    23.512] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
    [    23.514] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
    [    23.514] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
    [    23.514] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
    [    23.514] (==) Automatically adding devices
    [    23.514] (==) Automatically enabling devices
    [    23.514] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
    [    23.514] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
    [    23.514] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
    [    23.519] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
    [    23.519]    Entry deleted from font path.
    [    23.519] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
    [    23.519]    Entry deleted from font path.
    [    23.519] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
    [    23.519]    Entry deleted from font path.
    [    23.521] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
    [    23.521]    Entry deleted from font path.
    [    23.521] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
    [    23.521]    Entry deleted from font path.
    [    23.521] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        built-ins
    [    23.521] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    [    23.521] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
    [    23.521] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
    [    23.521] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
    [    23.521] (II) Loader magic: 0x55db6591b020
    [    23.521] (II) Module ABI versions:
    [    23.521]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
    [    23.521]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
    [    23.521]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
    [    23.521]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
    [    23.523] (++) using VT number 2
    
    [    23.527] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
    [    23.530] (--) PCI:*(1@0:0:0) 10de:0dc4:10b0:0401 rev 161, Mem @ 0xfc000000/16777216, 0xd0000000/134217728, 0xd8000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
    [    23.530] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
    [    23.532] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
    [    23.549] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    23.549]    compiled for 1.20.9, module version = 1.0.0
    [    23.549]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
    [    23.549] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
    [    23.549] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
    [    23.549] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
    [    23.718] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 0
    [    23.718] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
    [    23.718] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
    [    23.718] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
    [    23.718] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
    [    23.718] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
    [    23.719] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
    [    23.723] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    23.723]    compiled for 1.20.3, module version = 1.0.16
    [    23.723]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    [    23.723]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
    [    23.723] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
    [    23.723] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
    [    23.727] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    23.728]    compiled for 1.20.9, module version = 1.20.9
    [    23.728]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    [    23.728]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
    [    23.728] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
    [    23.728] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
    [    23.729] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    23.729]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 0.5.0
    [    23.729]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    [    23.729]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
    [    23.729] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
    [    23.729] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
    [    23.731] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    23.731]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 2.4.0
    [    23.731]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    [    23.731]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
    [    23.731] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Mon Jan 28 23:25:58 2019 -0500
    [    23.731] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
    [    23.731]    RIVA TNT            (NV04)
    [    23.731]    RIVA TNT2           (NV05)
    [    23.732]    GeForce 256         (NV10)
    [    23.732]    GeForce 2           (NV11, NV15)
    [    23.732]    GeForce 4MX         (NV17, NV18)
    [    23.732]    GeForce 3           (NV20)
    [    23.732]    GeForce 4Ti         (NV25, NV28)
    [    23.732]    GeForce FX          (NV3x)
    [    23.732]    GeForce 6           (NV4x)
    [    23.732]    GeForce 7           (G7x)
    [    23.732]    GeForce 8           (G8x)
    [    23.732]    GeForce 9           (G9x)
    [    23.732]    GeForce GTX 2xx/3xx (GT2xx)
    [    23.732]    GeForce GTX 4xx/5xx (GFxxx)
    [    23.732]    GeForce GTX 6xx/7xx (GKxxx)
    [    23.732]    GeForce GTX 9xx     (GMxxx)
    [    23.732]    GeForce GTX 10xx    (GPxxx)
    [    23.732] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
    [    23.732] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
    [    23.732] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
    [    23.876] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -19
    [    23.876] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
    [    23.876] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
    [    23.876] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
    [    23.876] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
    [    23.876] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
    [    23.876] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
    [    23.880] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    23.880]    compiled for 1.20.9, module version = 0.0.2
    [    23.880]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
    [    23.880] (**) FBDEV(1): claimed PCI slot 1@0:0:0
    [    23.880] (II) FBDEV(1): using default device
    [    23.880] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
    [    23.880] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
    [    23.880] (**) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
    [    23.880] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
    [    23.880] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
    [    23.880] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    [    23.880] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: EFI VGA (video memory: 3072kB)
    [    23.880] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
    [    23.880] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
    [    23.880] (II) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 1024x768 (pitch 1024)
    [    23.880] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current": 78.7 MHz, 59.9 kHz, 75.7 Hz
    [    23.880] (II) FBDEV(0): Modeline "current"x0.0   78.65  1024 1056 1184 1312  768 772 776 792 -hsync -vsync -csync (59.9 kHz b)
    [    23.880] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
    [    23.880] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
    [    23.880] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
    [    23.881] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
    [    23.886] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    23.886]    compiled for 1.20.9, module version = 1.0.0
    [    23.886]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
    [    23.886] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
    [    23.886] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
    [    23.886] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
    [    23.886] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
    [    23.889] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    23.889]    compiled for 1.20.9, module version = 1.1.0
    [    23.889]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
    [    23.889] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
    [    23.889] (II) Unloading vesa
    [    23.889] (II) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument (Screen blanking not supported by kernel - disabling)
    [    23.897] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled
    [    23.901] (**) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
    [    23.903] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
    [    23.903] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
    [    23.903] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
    [    23.904] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
    [    23.906] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
    [    23.906] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
    [    23.906] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
    [    23.907] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
    [    23.907] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
    [    23.907] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
    [    23.907] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
    [    23.907] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
    [    23.908] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
    [    23.908] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
    [    23.909] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
    [    23.909] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
    [    23.909] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
    [    23.909] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
    [    23.909] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
    [    23.910] (II) Initializing extension Present
    [    23.910] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
    [    23.911] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
    [    23.911] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
    [    23.911] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
    [    23.911] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
    [    23.911] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
    [    23.911] (II) Initializing extension GLX
    [    23.914] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
    [    24.218] (II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
    [    24.218] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
    [    24.218] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
    [    24.219] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
    [    24.220] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
    [    24.220] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
    [    24.287] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
    [    24.287] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
    [    24.287] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
    [    24.287] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
    [    24.296] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    24.296]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.29.0
    [    24.296]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
    [    24.296]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
    [    24.296] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
    [    24.297] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event1 13:65 fd 22 paused 0
    [    24.297] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
    [    24.297] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
    [    24.297] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
    [    24.318] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
    [    24.318] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
    [    24.318] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
    [    24.318] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
    [    24.318] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
    [    24.318] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
    [    24.319] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
    [    24.322] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
    [    24.322] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
    [    24.325] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
    [    24.325] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
    [    24.325] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
    [    24.326] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event0 13:64 fd 25 paused 0
    [    24.326] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
    [    24.327] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
    [    24.327] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
    [    24.328] (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
    [    24.328] (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
    [    24.328] (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
    [    24.328] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
    [    24.328] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
    [    24.328] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
    [    24.328] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
    [    24.329] (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
    [    24.330] (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
    [    24.330] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event4)
    [    24.331] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    24.331] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    24.331] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event5)
    [    24.331] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    24.331] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    24.332] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event6)
    [    24.332] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    24.332] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    24.332] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event7)
    [    24.332] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    24.332] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    24.332] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Line (/dev/input/event10)
    [    24.333] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    24.333] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    24.333] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Line Out (/dev/input/event11)
    [    24.333] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    24.333] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    24.333] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Rear Mic (/dev/input/event8)
    [    24.333] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    24.333] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    24.334] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Front Mic (/dev/input/event9)
    [    24.334] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    24.334] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    24.335] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event3)
    [    24.335] (**) PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
    [    24.335] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse'
    [    24.338] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 26 paused 0
    [    24.338] (**) PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse: always reports core events
    [    24.338] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
    [    24.338] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
    [    24.339] (II) event3  - PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
    [    24.340] (II) event3  - PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse: device is a pointer
    [    24.340] (II) event3  - PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse: device removed
    [    24.340] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb7/7-3/7-3:1.0/0003:03F0:0941.0001/input/input3/event3"
    [    24.341] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 8)
    [    24.341] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
    [    24.341] (**) PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
    [    24.341] (**) PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
    [    24.341] (**) PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
    [    24.343] (II) event3  - PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
    [    24.344] (II) event3  - PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse: device is a pointer
    [    24.345] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
    [    24.345] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    24.345] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    24.345] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event2)
    [    24.345] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
    [    24.345] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
    [    24.348] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event2 13:66 fd 27 paused 0
    [    24.348] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
    [    24.348] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
    [    24.348] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
    [    24.350] (II) event2  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
    [    24.350] (II) event2  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
    [    24.350] (II) event2  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
    [    24.350] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2/event2"
    [    24.350] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
    [    24.350] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
    [    24.351] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
    [    24.352] (II) event2  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
    [    24.352] (II) event2  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
```

Comment: you really use a 450? That GPU is not supported anymore, although you can't upgrade now... Try installing an old driver maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems multiple people have trouble with this right now. Myself included, but I managed to fix it. I will give you a long explanation with as much data as possible, although I'm not an expert on Linux. Everything I know is essentially copy pasting code from the internet, hoping it works.

I'm running nvidia gtx 960, 460.39 driver, and dualbooting ubuntu 20.04 with windows 10. No issues on windows. When I boot ubuntu, I immediately experience heavy stuttering, my secondary monitor isn't working and all windows are drawing slowly on screen from top to bottom.

Last time I had this issue (~2 months ago), simple driver reinstall worked for me.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-driver-460
```

That didn't work for me today. I attempted to purge the drivers with:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge nvidia-driver-460 && sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460
```

But that didn't work either. Using `nvidia-smi` I got following result:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Using `sudo dkms status` I got following result:

```
nvidia, 460.39, 5.8.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

Googling led me to this [nvidia forum post](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldn-t-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver-after-updating-ubuntu-20-04/170985/7), which seems to had the same issues. Coincidentally, the post is less than 20 hours old as of writing this response. From the forum post (specifically comment #7) I used following code:

```
sudo dkms remove nvidia/460.39 --all
sudo dkms install --force nvidia/460.39 -k $(uname -r)
sudo update-initramfs -u
sync
reboot
```

Like a typical trained monkey user, I used those commands without knowing what they do. But after reboot my system works just fine. Hope this helps to somebody.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm.

Comment: The first step, simple driver reinstall, worked for me.

Comment: For those, who get `kernel cannot be found error`, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787507/error-your-kernel-headers-for-kernel-3-13-0-69-generic-cannot-be-found-cant) helped me.

Answer (score 0):

From nvidia website, they released a 390.141 in Jan 2021 that fixes the failure to install under kernel 5.8.

I tested on an freshly installed ubuntu 18.04 by selecting the 390.141 from the "additional drivers" and using the kernel 5.8.0 from the mainline kernel tool. It's working now.

So, now I am removing all the newer kernel from mainline, remove nvidia 390.141 and used back the x.org driver.. Upgrading to ubuntu 20.04.2. I use ubuntu mainline kernel tool to install kernel 5.8.0 and install the 390.141 driver from the "additional drivers" tab. Viola, I have a working nvidia 390.141 in kernel 5.8.0.

Answer (score -1):

I am just posting this answer to help anyone that faced the same problem as I did. My screen had the same problem, and it was caused because it did not detected the NVIDIA drivers. However, even though I correctly installed everything, it was still failing.

At the end, the problem was a gnome plugin that I installed a couples of days before. So, if reinstalling NVIDIA your problem persists, I would advise to check any GNOME plugin that you might have installed recently.

Comment: It's nice to see that people downvote something that could potentially help someone. I consider this is a good answer since a lot of plugins that worked for Ubuntu 18.04 do not work in Ubuntu 20.04 or higher, so this may be a common problem. As I mentioned as well, you should first try to reinstall NVIDIA as the accepted answer says. Every time I use this platform I feel that people does not want you to help.