# Video driver suddenly changed to llvmpipe upon startup

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, video

I had shut down my pc a little while ago, and when I booted it up just now, the screen is all stretched and low resolution, I went into my settings and it says my graphics is llvmpipe, I didn't install it recently so I don't know what caused this

`lspci -nn | grep VGA`

shows that my GPU is being detected, and I also checked software & updates and looked at the additional drivers and it was picking up my GPU there too, and it said I was using the recommended driver

System Specs:
GPU: Gtx 1650
CPU: Ryzen 5 3400G
RAM: 16GB @ 3000mHz

Comment: I'd check out [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323927/nvidia-driver-not-detected-screen-is-on-low-resolution) post.

Answer (score 0):

Although i dont know why this happend, i managed to fix it by getting the driver file directly from nvidia and not using Software & updates or using `sudo apt {driver name}`