# Monitor resolution is suddenly low, with no option to change it

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display-resolution

I've been using ubuntu (dual-boot) for a few weeks now and today the resolution went to 1024x768, with no way to change it.

I first tried the fix where you update the grub file to the resolution of the monitor, in my case 2640x1440. After updating grub and restarting, nothing changed.

Then I went to the 'software and updates' app and tried switching from the nouveau driver to the (proprietary,tested) Nvidia open kernel 520 driver. Then I restarted and nothing changed.

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, with a 3060ti GPU

Here's some of the commands I ran, to give you more info:

```
:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

:~$ uname -r
5.15.0-52-generic

:~$ xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* 

:~$ lspci | grep VG
26:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104 [GeForce RTX 3060 Ti] (rev a1)

:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for (): 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA104 [GeForce RTX 3060 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:26:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:57 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1024,768
```

I'm not very familiar with linux, so I'm not sure if I should try and follow the answer from this post, where the solution was to purge the driver,reinstall, and (i think) force the driver to work with the kernel?:

[nvidia driver not detected. Screen is on low resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323927/nvidia-driver-not-detected-screen-is-on-low-resolution)

Comment: No, that answer is likely not applicable. Just disable Secure Boot in UEFI and try again.

Comment: Secure boot was never enabled

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text. Cut and paste the text into the body of the question. Pictures force the persona trying to help to leave the question to see them, they can not be searched and often have cut off info. Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu being used.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the question now