# Virtualbox: No suitable module for running kernel foun, Ubuntu 22.04, Kernel 5.15.0-57-generic

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 22.04

I can't install Virtualbox on Ubuntu 22.04. I must admit i did change kernel for some reasons, and I don't know if my current kernel (5.15.0-57-generic) is the right one to run Virtualbox...

I tried:

- change kernel with different versions
- uninstall / purge / reinstall virtualbox-dkms
- reinstall headers

Nothing work... I would like to avoid completely reinstall ubuntu...

This is not dupliaction of this, yet tried all that...
[Unable to install VirtualBox on Ubuntu 12.10: Kernel headers cannot be found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258521/unable-to-install-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-12-10-kernel-headers-cannot-be-found)

Thanks

[image: install terminal]

[image: header updated]

[image: modprobe error]

Comment: Hello, Indeed it's a similar question. But as I said, I already tried all that : download headers, even tried to compile "male prepare"...etc. This DOES NOT work on my case. I also tried to install from official site, Virtualbox7, has exactly same problem.

Comment: To discuss why your question was closed open a question here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/ and you can make your case...